# Type error: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
    import Papa from "papaparse";
    
    function App() {
      const [file, setFile] = useState();
      const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
      const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState([]);
    
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
    
      const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
         Papa.parse(e.target.files[0], {
         header: true,
         skipEmptyLines: true,
         complete: function (results) {
           console.log(results.data)
         },
       });    
      };
            
 
         
    
      const csvFileToArray = (string) => {
        Papa.parse(string, {
          header: true,
          skipEmptyLines: true,
          complete: function (results) {
            //console.log('Parsing Results:', results);
            if (Array.isArray(results.data)) {
              const parsedArray = results.data.map((row) => {
                const obj = {};
                for (let key in row) {
                  obj[key.trim()] = row[key].trim();
                }
                return obj;
              });
              setArray(parsedArray);
            } else {
              console.error('Error parsing CSV data.');
            }
          },  
        });
      };
      
      
      const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        if (file) {
          fileReader.onload = function (event) {
            const text = event.target.result;
            csvFileToArray(text);
          };
    
          fileReader.readAsText(file); 
        }
      };

const handlePredict = async (event) => {
        console.log('array',array) 
        event.preventDefault()
        try { 
          const response = await fetch('/multi_airpredict', {                                                                                             
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(array),
          });
    
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Prediction failed');
          }
    
    
          const data = await response.json();
          setPredictions(data.predictions);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } 
      };
    
      const headerKeys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...array));
    
      return (
        <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>    
          <h1>CSV IMPORT</h1> 
          <form>
            <input
              type="file"
              id="csvFileInput"
              accept=".csv"
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
    
            <button onClick={handleOnSubmit}>IMPORT CSV</button>
    
            <button onClick={handlePredict}>PREDICT</button>
          </form>
    
          <br />
    
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr key="header">
                {headerKeys.map((key) => (
                  <th key={key}>{key}</th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            </thead>
    
           <tbody>
              {array.map((item, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  {Object.values(item).map((val, index) => (
                    <td key={index}>{val}</td>
                  ))}
                </tr>  
              ))}
            </tbody> 
                  </table>
    
                    
          <div>
            <h2>Predictions</h2>
            <ul>
              {predictions.map((prediction, index) => (
                <li key={index}>{prediction}</li>
              ))}
              </ul>
             
         
    
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

This is a project which takes a csv file, converts it to array and give to the prediction model to print predictions for all rows together. I am still still working on the flask api part which can accept whole csv as input. so i think this error is happening because currently there are no predicted values present. still if anyone can help to solve this?

Comment: `predictions` is undefined

Comment: Not sure what your code is doing and what your question is.
But the error means that `predictions` is undefined.

Comment: function App() {
  const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState([]);          it is defined

Comment: So you change it to `undefined` later. As a result of `fetch` perhaps

Comment: Can you please show whole component.

Comment: `data.predictions` is `undefined`

Comment: i uploaded whole code below.

Comment: do console.log(data) after `const data = await response.json();`

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info to your question.

With the given information, I can infer the predictions is still null at the moment when is called so try to do some validation before to make sure that function finish to fetch

like this

```
const predictions = await getinDatafromSVG()
if (!predictions) retrun <>loading</>
return  <ul> {predictions.map((prediction, index) => ( <li key={index}>{prediction}</li> ))} </ul>
```